# Find-And-Replace Any Selected Text

Tags: windows, hotkeys, find-and-replace

**Goal:** Quick find-and-replace for active selected text in any application.

**Description:**
I want a utility to quickly perform a predetermined find-and-replace for the current selected text in the active application.  I would highlight some text, press a hotkey, and the selected text would be replaced according to the filter.

This functionality would be useful for performing find-and-replace quickly when other programmatic methods are not readily available (renaming data files to match new filename scheme, removing the same text from each record in some application, etc).

**Ideas:** global hotkey editor, windows clipboard monitor, etc.

Thoughts?

Comment: You could setup a basic macro in Autohotkey (www.autohotkey.com). If you have text selected then whatever keystrokes are in the macro will automatically replace it.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://www.phraseexpress.com) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end (2.5 years later), I just use a combination of tools based on what I need to search-and-replace.  For short replacements, I used AutoHotkey Hotstrings.  Other times, I'll copy-and-paste to and from Notepad++ and use its search and replace.  Other times, a batch file or cygwin bash script gets the job done.